# Scrapy Spider not returning response

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to spiders and have this basic code to scrap reedsy.
I was able to locate and pull out the elements I need in the scrapy shell but my code is not working. The error message is so large, I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
import scrapy

class PublisherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mycrawler'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.reedsy.com/publishers/african-american/']
   
    def parse(self, response):
        for publishers in response.css('div.panel-body'):
            yield {
                'Publisher': response.css('h3.text-heavy::text').get().replace('\n',''),
                'url' : response.css('a.text-blue').attrib['href'],
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4e2i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f33e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZK4V.png)

Comment: Can you attach the error even though it is large.

Comment: Yes, just posted!

Comment: To avoid `if` statement you can also use `response.css('h3.text-heavy::text').get(default='').strip()`

Comment: Thanks for response but unfortunately that did not work for me. I got an error message of ' ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in the traceback is `NoneType object has no attribute replace`.

This means that the css selector that you call `.replace('\n','')` is evaluating to `None`, which doesn't have a replace method.

The cause for this error is because your initial selector `div.panel-body` is used in more than one way within the page.  One way is to denote each of the containers that house the information that you are trying to extract, but the class is additionally used near the footer of the page, which is the part that is giving you the error.

What you can do to avoid this is to evaluate the selector expressions first, then test to see if those evaluated to `None` and if not only then should you do any postprocessing and yield the result.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class PublisherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mycrawler'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.reedsy.com/publishers/african-american/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for publishers in response.css('div.panel-body'):
            publisher = publishers.css('h3.text-heavy::text').get()
            url = publishers.css('a.text-blue::attr(href)').get()
            if publisher and url:
                yield {"Publisher": publisher.strip(), "url": url}
```